# Android how to get id from ArrayAdapter by clicking ImageView

Tags: android

I have placed in ArrayAdapter an ImageView, the list looks like this:

Name1     |ImageView|

Name2     |ImageView|

Name3     |ImageView|

end so on..

I don't know how to get an item id after clicking ImageView.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View contextView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder viewHolder;
    View rowView = contextView;
    final CardList list = _cardList.get(position);

    if (rowView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = _context.getLayoutInflater();
        rowView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.cardlist_viewlist_tpl, null, true);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.tvCardListName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvCardListName);
        viewHolder.btnCardListLearn = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.btnCardListLearn);
        viewHolder.btnCardListLearn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(_context, LearningCardActivity.class);

                //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                //this doesn't work, I always get 1st positon Id
                intent.putExtra(LearningCardActivity.CURRENT_CARD_LIST_ID, list.getId());
                //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

                _context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        rowView.setTag(viewHolder); 
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.tvCardListName.setText(list.getName());

    return rowView;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're re-using the `rowView/contextView` and that you only set your onClickListener if the rowView equals `null`. That basically means that the listener on your `viewholder` object will only be set the first time `getView()` gets called. Hence you will always see the same first item's id .

If you want to set the listener for every row, you will need to change the logic and move the `setOnClickListener()` call.

```
public View getView(int position, View contextView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = contextView;
    if (rowView == null) {
        // Code here will only be run the very first time 
        // (when the row view hasn't been constructed yet)
    } else {
        // Code here will be run after that, since we're 
        // re-using the row's view
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add an attribute on your ViewHolder class like:

```
static class ViewHolder {

   //...

   int position;

}
```

You set this attribute before return the view:

```
//...
viewHolder.position = position;
return rowView;
```

Now you can use the item ID on your listener using holder.position.
In your case, it should be something like this:

```
//...
 intent.putExtra(LearningCardActivity.CURRENT_CARD_LIST_ID, holder.position);
//...
```

I'm not sure if its the better way to do that but it works for me...

Based on: http://www.itsalif.info/content/custom-list-views-icons-and-listeners-android#comment-6526